# Two models in same view in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to asp.net & I'm trying to make a website with asp.net mvc 4 & EF6 where I need two models to work under the same view. I've tried a lot but couldn't figure out how to make that work. Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult AfterLogin()
    {
        if (Session["UserNAME"] != null)
        {
            var firstmodel = new MyViewModel { stats = db.stats.ToList() };
            var secondmodel = new MyViewModel { mans = db.mans.ToList() };
            return View(firstmodel);   //How can I also add the "secondmodel"?
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<stat> stats { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<man> mans { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use both model at the same time? Need this help badly. Tnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only bind to one model.

Either create a new model that contains both of the models you want to use.

```
public class AfterLoginModel
{
    public MyViewModel Stats { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel Mans { get; set; }
}
```

or in your case, since they are the exact same model, you could also set both the `stats` and `mans` properties and pass in a single MyViewModel.

```
var model = new MyViewModel { 
                               stats = db.stats.ToList(),
                               mans = db.mans.ToList()
                            };
return View(model);
```

Comment: The 2nd part worked for me. Its so simple & I'm so stupid for didn't try hard enough. Tnx. :)

Answer (score 3):

Make a model that contains both

```
public class CombinedModel
{
    public MyVieModel Model1 {get;set;}
    public MyVieModel Model2 {get;set;}
}
```

Use that for the view

```
public ActionResult AfterLogin()
{
    if (Session["UserNAME"] != null)
    {
        var firstmodel = new MyViewModel { stats = db.stats.ToList() };
        var secondmodel = new MyViewModel { mans = db.mans.ToList() };
        return View(new CombinedModel(){
           Model1 = firstmodel,
           Model2 = secondmodel
       });   //
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Brandon and Jamiec's answers are definitely better for this situation, but if you *really* don't want to change the model, or create a new class then you can always add data to the `ViewBag`. In your Controller method:

```
 ViewBag.SecondModel = new MyViewModel { mans = db.mans.ToList() };
```

then in the view you can call it like:

```
@{
   MyViewModel secondModel = (MyViewModel) ViewBag.SecondModel;
 }
```

Note that you need to use the cast because anything in the `ViewBag` is dynamically typed.